# How to get around u_path_length bug in iOS before iOS 10.2

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, fragment-shader, skshapenode

**The problem:** On a device running a problematic iOS version, if `u_path_length` is even accessed it breaks the whole SpriteKit view - it just goes all black.

**The long explanation:**

There seems to be a bug with shaders in versions of iOS previous to 10.2... at least it works on a iOS 10.2 device I have, and it doesn't on a iOS 9.3.5 device.

The things I am working with comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624474/129202

There is a comment there about this issue, but I can't find out how to work around it. And can't find any other references to this issue yet.

```
    // prior to a fix in iOS 10.2, bug #27989113  "SKShader/SKShapeNode: u_path_length is not set unless shouldUseLocalStrokeBuffers() is true"  
    // add a few points to work around this bug in iOS 10-10.1 ->  
    // for i in 0...15 {  
    //    path1.addLine( to: CGPoint( x: 0, y: strokeHeight + CGFloat( 0.001 ) * CGFloat( i ) ) )  
    // }
```

I am using a shader for a SKShapeNode. The shape is a simple circle.
The shader is in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755880/129202

Confirmed working iOS versions

- iOS 10.2
- iOS 10.1.1

Not working

- iOS 9.3.5
- iOS 9.3.4